# Concatenate a list for plot labels

Tags: r

I want to create intervals (discretize/bin) of continuous variables to plot a choropleth map using ggplot. After reading various threads, I decided to use `cut` and `quantile` to eliminate the problems of: a) manually creating bins, and b) taking care of dominant states (otherwise, I had to manually to create bins and see the map and readjust the bins).

However, I am facing another problem now. Intervals coming out of `cut` are hardly pretty. So, I am trying to follow this [example](http://www.sigmafield.org/comment/13) and this [example](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/23506-Controlling-Automated-Labels-in-Cut) to come up with my pretty labels.

Here is my list:

```
x <- seq(1,50)
```

Rounded quantiles:

```
qs_x <- round(quantile(x, probs=c(seq(0,0.8,by=0.2),0.9)))
```

which results:

```
 0% 20% 40% 60% 80% 90% 
 1  11  21  30  40  45
```

Using these cuts, I want to come up with these labels:

```
1-11, 12-21, 22-30, 31-40, 41-45, 45+
```

I am sure there is an easy solution to convert a list using some `apply` function, but I am not well-versed with those functions.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3-liner produces the output you want, without using `apply`.

```
labels <- paste(qs_x+1, qs_x[-1], sep="-")
labels[1] <- paste(qs_x[1], qs_x[2], sep="-")
labels[length(labels)] <- paste(tail(qs_x, 1), "+", sep = "")
```

The first line constructs labels of the form `(x1 + 1) - x2`, the second line fixes the first label, and the third line fixes the last label. Here is the output

```
> labels
[1] "1-11"  "12-21" "22-30" "31-40" "41-45" "45+"
```

Comment: There is an extra label (41-45) in the output I provided, I assume that's what you need.

Comment: thank you very much (yes, I do need that label that I missed from my example). I did something similar using a `for` loop. I think your code is better. Before I accept your answer, I will wait for some more time to see whether someone has even cleverer solution.